# Firebase Join group and become members

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So currently my app has the function to create a group, in my case I call it a team, where users can choose to join the team they want. Users can click on the list of team and choose to join them. Once they joined, they can click the team again and it will directs them to a chat room. I'm using Firebase as my backend.

So here's my problem, should I create a child named "Members" that stores the team ID and its member? If so, how should I do it? I don't know how or where this member thing should be stored and the moment the user leaves, the members in the database should be updated. Would really appreciate if someone could help me.

This is where the list of team is display.

MainActivity:

```
//firebase auth object
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

EditText editTextName;
EditText textDate;
EditText textTime;
Spinner spinnerSport;
ListView listViewTeams;
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;

//a list to store all the team from firebase database
List<Team> teams;

//our database reference object
DatabaseReference databaseTeams;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    mSheetLayout.setFab(mFab);
    mSheetLayout.setFabAnimationEndListener(this);

    //initializing firebase authentication object
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //if the user is not logged in
    //that means current user will return null
    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
        //closing this activity
        finish();
        //starting login activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
    }

    //getting current user
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    //getting the reference of teams node
    databaseTeams = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("teams");

    //getting views
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    spinnerSport = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSports);
    listViewTeams = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTeams);
    textDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textDate);
    textTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textTime);




    //list to store teams
    teams = new ArrayList<>();



    //attaching listener to listview
    listViewTeams.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //getting the selected team
            Team team = teams.get(i);

            //creating an intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatRoomActivity.class);

            //putting team name and id to intent
            intent.putExtra(TEAM_ID, team.getTeamId());
            intent.putExtra(TEAM_NAME, team.getTeamName());

            //starting the activity with intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    listViewTeams.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Team team = teams.get(i);
            showUpdateDeleteDialog(team.getTeamId(), team.getTeamName());
            return true;
        }
    });

}

private void showUpdateDeleteDialog(final String teamId, String teamName) {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_dialog, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText editTextName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    final Spinner spinnerSport = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSports);
    final Button buttonUpdate = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdateTeam);
    final Button buttonDelete = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDeleteTeam);
    final EditText textDate = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
    final EditText textTime = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textTime);

    dialogBuilder.setTitle(teamName);
    final AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
    b.show();

    // perform click event on edit text
    textDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // calender class's instance and get current date , month and year from calender
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
            // date picker dialog
            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                            textDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    // perform click event listener on edit text
    textTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    textTime.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                }
            }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();

        }
    });


    buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
            String sport = spinnerSport.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String owner = user.getUid();
            String date = textDate.getText().toString();
            String time = textTime.getText().toString();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                updateTeam(teamId, name, sport, owner, date, time);
                b.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });


    buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            deleteTeam(teamId);
            b.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

private boolean updateTeam(String id, String name, String sport, String owner, String date, String time) {
    //getting the specified team reference
    DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("teams").child(id);

    //updating team
    Team team = new Team(id, name, sport, owner, date, time);
    dR.setValue(team);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Team Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}

private boolean deleteTeam(String id) {
    //getting the specified artist reference
    DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("teams").child(id);

    //removing team
    dR.removeValue();

    //getting the tracks reference for the specified artist
    DatabaseReference drTracks = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tracks").child(id);

    //removing all tracks
    drTracks.removeValue();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Team Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //attaching value event listener
    databaseTeams.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //clearing the previous team list
            teams.clear();

            //iterating through all the nodes
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //getting team
                Team team = postSnapshot.getValue(Team.class);
                //adding team to the list
                teams.add(team);
            }

            //creating adapter
            TeamList teamAdapter = new TeamList(MainActivity.this, teams);
            //attaching adapter to the listview
            listViewTeams.setAdapter(teamAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_logout:
            //logout code
            //logging out the user
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            //closing activity
            finish();
            //starting login activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


}
```

This is the dialog which will be appeared when user click on one of the team if he/she is not a member yet.

join_dialog.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Do you want to join this team?"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonYes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Yes" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="No" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I haven't added any button to allow users to leave team yet, let's just assume there is one. [image: Database]

And this is what my database looks like, the chat is currently accessible regardless of which team u click, I'll get to that on other time. Let me know if there's any insufficient information, I will provide as much as I can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an efficient medium to digest and debug large swaths of code. Please provide only the [minimum complete code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it's quite useful).

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to topic? ,  I mean create a topic with your team name and subscribe all the users to it and when user leaves the group unsubscribe the user from that particular topic .https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Comment: @MuhibPirani Oh no, what i want is something like whatsapp, creating a group and lets other to join in and chat. Instead of group, the word I'm using is "team". Not subscribe to certain team to get live scores or something like that.

Comment: Can I ask how to bump my question up so that others could see it?

Comment: Is there no one else that can help me or guide me to solve my problems?